# Similar triangles with side lengths satisfying linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, triangles, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

Suppose we want to find/describe the side lengths of $n$ different triangles given that (1) they are all similar to one another and (2) their side lengths satisfy a given homogeneous system of linear equations. Clearly the problems here is that the proportions that result from the similarity requirement are nonlinear. (They can be written in quadratic form though.) Is there any way to deal with this problem algebraically?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. What prevents you from just solving the linear systems?

Comment: The triangles are similar, which means that the side lengths are proportional. This gives us a bunch of equations of the form $a_1/a_2=b_1/b_2$ for example, which are NOT linear.

Comment: 'their side lengths satisfy a given homogeneous system of linear equations'. Can you give an example of this problem?